# How do I make a local variable become the value of another local variable in a different script

Tags: scripting, roblox

I am making a jumping game and I want the JumpBoost value on the leader board to be the Value of the JumpBoost of the object

```
local boostPart = script.Parent
local jump = leaderstats.gold.Value
local boostedJumpPower = jump.Value
local function onPartTouch(otherPart)
    local partParent = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if ( humanoid ) then
        boostPart.CanCollide = false
        local currentJumpPower = humanoid.JumpPower
        if ( currentJumpPower < boostedJumpPower ) then
            humanoid.JumpPower = boostedJumpPower
            wait(5)
            humanoid.JumpPower = currentJumpPower
        end
    end
end
boostPart.Touched:Connect(onPartTouch)
```

I tried this but It didn't work and I cant think of another way

If I test the game and jump after touching the object my Jump is normal not the leader stats amount

Comment: Kylaaa could you  help me with my game you seem to know what your doing and I'm pretty new to this stuff also i changed from what I had to what you had but it didn't change the  out come can you explain more so how to do it .

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are simply not accessing the leaderstats value properly.

There is a difference between the Player you find in `game.Players` and the one in `game.Workspace`. The one in `game.Players` is where the leaderstats folder is, and the one in `game.Workspace` is where the player's humanoid lives.

In order to alter the leaderstats values, you need to use the humanoid to know which player touched the part, but then get the actual Player object from `game.Players` to properly access the folder.

```
local boostPart = script.Parent

local function onPartTouch(otherPart)
    -- get the player that touched the boost block
    local partParent = otherPart.Parent
    local humanoid = partParent:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Humanoid")
    if ( humanoid ) then
        -- a player touched this, prevent more collisions
        boostPart.CanCollide = false

        -- get the current player's jump power by looking into the players leaderstats
        local playerService = game.Players
        local playerName = partParent.Name
        local currentPlayer = playerService[playerName]
        local playerGold = currentPlayer.leaderstats.gold.Value -- << gold?

        -- give the player a temporary boost
        local currentJumpPower = humanoid.JumpPower
        if ( currentJumpPower < playerGold) then
            humanoid.JumpPower = playerGold

            -- reset the player's jump power
            wait(5)
            humanoid.JumpPower = currentJumpPower
        end
    end
end
boostPart.Touched:Connect(onPartTouch)
```

This should allow you to properly read from the leaderstats values. If you want to alter them, you can use the same system for navigating into the Players folder and changing the values.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question, "How do I make a local variable become the value of a local variable in another script", Roblox has a system for passing data using [BindableEvents](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/BindableEvent) and [BindableFunctions](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/BindableFunction).

A simple example of this assumes you have a BindableEvent in the workspace.

Local Script 1:

```
local myValue = 1
local bEvent = game.Workspace.BindableEvent

-- listen for actions fired from other scripts
bEvent.Event:Connect(function(newValue)
    myValue = newValue
    print("Script 1 - myValue has changed to ", myValue)
end

print("Script 1 - myValue originally equals ", myValue)
```

Local Script 2 :

```
wait(1)
local bEvent = game.Workspace.BindableEvent

-- tell the other scripts that the value has changed
print("Script 2 - firing change signal")
bEvent:Fire(10)
```

This kind of system is useful if you have a lot of different moving parts and you want a centralized way for communicating changes, and don't want to build a custom data passing system.